# Python Selenium - Wait until Element is loaded

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I often have the problem with Selenium that the script crashes because I want to access an element that is not loaded yet.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method": "xpath", "selector":"//*[@id="ipv4_info"]/span[3]"}
```

Currently I do it that way, that I put a `time.sleep(30)` before such places, but sometimes it takes longer or shorter until the element loads.

Is there any way to wait until the element is loaded and as soon as it is loaded immediately continue with the rest of the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *XPATH*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id="ipv4_info"]/span[3]")))
  ```
- *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ipv4_info span:nth-child(3)")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: What does the 20 stand for?

Comment: @AbduladilSunnat the timeout in seconds